# WSO2 APIM - Remove Authorization header from API LOG

Tags: header, wso2, log4j, wso2-api-manager

I want to remove from api.log file the authorization header that appears there:

```
[2022-02-08 15:00:57,703]  INFO {API_LOG} pizzashack - {"headers":["accept=application/json",...,"Connection=keep-alive","Host=localhost:8243","authorization=Bearer yJraWQiOiJnYXRld2F5X3g...","Origin=https://localhost:9443"..
```

I want to delete that token inside authorization header, how can i do it? I have tried with log4jproperties adding:

```
 logger.API_LOGGER.property.apim.message = %replace{%msg}{authorization:[^,]*}{"Authorization: Bearer ***"}{}
```

But it gives me an error when restarting APIM.

Comment: What is the APIM version you are using?

Comment: APIM 4.1.0 right now @ycr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using log-masking[1].

A sample config is shown below.

1. Add below masking regex for JWT in deployment.toml (Please note this is a sample only, you may have to improve this to only capture JWTs, )

```
[masking_pattern.properties]
"JWT" = ' \\b([a-zA-Z0-9_=]+)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9_=]+)\\.([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\+\\/=]*)\\"'
```

2. Enable log masking for API_LOGGER by updating log pattern as below.

```
appender.API_LOGFILE.layout.pattern = [%d] %5p {%c} %X{apiName} - %mm%ex%n
```

[1]. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/administer/logging-and-monitoring/logging/masking-sensitive-information-in-logs/

Comment: I tried it but I cant get it work..

Comment: did you append an extra `m` after `%m` in `appender.API_LOGFILE.layout.pattern`  (i.e %mm%ex%n) ? And did you try with the same regex I specified above ?

Comment: It worked! The problem was i append with API_LOGFILE_CONSOLE not API_LOGFILE, so it was just working on the console stdout. thanks!